# How can I recover my deleted firebase flutter base project

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have used my project yesterday, but when I try to open the console I could not see my project and I have not received any email.
How can I recover it.

Comment: I linked the standard recovery procedure. If the project isn't showing up there, could it be that you created it under a different account?

Comment: Actually the problem is that, I made client as owner and he removed me from the firebase project

Comment: Unfortunately that happens regularly and is not something that you revert after the fact. You'll have to discuss this with the client, as it's not a technical problem.